# How to delete Files,MainFolder and SubFolders

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a problem in deleting Files,MainFolder And SubFolders in a Directory. I want to delete all the Files,MainFolders and Subfolders after the work is finish . I am using this following code.

```
        private void bgAtoZ_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
           string Path1 = (string)(Application.StartupPath + "\\TEMP\\a-z\\test" + "\\" +name);
           StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1);
           string str = reader1.ReadToEnd();
           reader1.Close();
           reader1.Dispose();
           File.Delete(Path1);
         }
```

If anyone Would help me it would be nice for me.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: "I am having a problem " - and that would be?

Comment: r u getting any errors with this code.

Comment: no, its only deleting files in the folder not the folder and subfolders

Comment: Why are you reading all the files?

Comment: to write in another directory

Comment: Then why don't you use Directory.Move()? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx

Answer (score 12):

```
Direcory.Delete(path, true);
```

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for a:

```
Directory.Delete(Path1, true)
```

that will delete folders and files contained.

Answer (score 3):

`Directory.Delete(@"c:\test", true);` would do it

Answer (score 1):

```
 new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Temp").Delete(true);

 //Or

 System.IO.Directory.Delete("C:\Temp", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO; 
private void EmptyFolder(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
  foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
  {
    file.Delete();
  }
  foreach (DirectoryInfo subfolder in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
  {
    EmptyFolder(subfolder);
  }
}
```

To use the code:

```
EmptyFolder(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\yourPath"))
```

Taken from [here](http://www.ceveni.com/2008/03/delete-files-in-folder-and-subfolders.html).